# Get the label value of a jquery animated counter label through asp.net code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Hello I have a jquery animated counter which I downloaded from `http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Animated-Number-Counter-Plugin-For-jQuery-animationCounter-js.html`. Now i want to get the value of the counter on the click of an asp.net button. I have tried it the normal way it returns a blank figure(empty) yet the counter has counted up to 1000. Here is my code :

```
<span id="lblprofit" runat="server" class="profit"></span>

Protected Sub btnshow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    dim value as string = lblprofit.InnerHtml
    Response.Redirect("newpage")
End Sub
```

here is the `javascript` for the counter after my own edit :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#counter-block').ready(function () {

        $('.profit').animationCounter({
            start: 0,
            step: 2,
            delay: 2000,
            end: 40000,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Each time i click the button and use break point the profit innerhtml or value returns empty. have also tried using asp.net label control its the same thing too.

Comment: You can't. The javascript writes on the client side and the server side can't read it. You can use a webservice to send the info to the server.

Comment: But i have seen someone done it in php